# Clash of Clans question about the an empty space next to someone's level

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans, what does it mean when there is an empty space next to someone's level?  In the space where a symbol representing what league they are in normally shows.  Like a Roman numeral I, II, or III.

Comment: iFitb.png Like number 11 in this pic.

Comment: Probably that they aren't in any league because they haven't attacked since the leagues reset.  I believe the reset happens once every 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

An empty shield means that the player is not in a league, like so: ([Example](http://cdn.withoutthesarcasm.com/wp-content/uploads/Missing-League-Badge.jpg?e2af74)). However, once the player attacks and has at least 400 trophies, they will have a shield ranging from [Bronze 3 to Champion](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130414172353/clashofclans/images/2/23/SneakPeek_-_League_Levels.png). The current shield will remain for the rest of the current 2 week session, also known as a "league season".

Comment: I believe these 2 week periods are called "seasons" and they reset every other sunday